# Woocommerce and Paypal (Sandbox)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to include Paypal as payment method in a Woocommerce shop. I have created a developer account with a buyer and a business sandbox account.

I added the business sandbox account in Woocommerce at Paypal settings as well as the API settings of the business sandbox account.

When ordering I can choose Paypal and will get redirected to Paypal. Everything seems to work and I login with the buyer sandbox account. But then a "system error" occurs and I will get redirected to my shop. The order view shows this order as not completed.

Is there an error or does the Sandbox feature not involve correct paying?

Best regards and thank you for the help
Christian

Comment: Issue should be different. Sandbox should work as normal account. Do you have any information on error/warning?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I could post a screenshot, but it is a German error message. How can I display it in English?

Answer (score 1):

There are some settings in wp-admin to enable testmode payment and option to add buyer and vendor email id. Please check those settings twice.

Is there any error in your console? Please check it.

or you may use this [link](https://clickwp.com/blog/woocommerce-paypal-sandbox/) to verify all your settings and flow.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. If I uncheck the Sandbox in my Woocommerce PayPal settings, it goes to PayPal just fine. It's just the Sandbox that is delivering the error.

[Woocommerce Sandbox Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uldO.png)

The Sandbox has only been an issue since updating WooCommerce. I'm currently using 3.0.4 when I got this error.

Comment: I discovered the same thing two days ago. Unchecked the sandbox setting and payment ist working as it should. Updated to 3.0.4 today and will test again, but I would agree, that sandbox feature is an issue...